# how to get the default color when draw a line for JSeparator

Tags: java, swing

I override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of the **JSeparator** to get a thicker line and different color when needed.

But I cannot get its **original default color**. The color changed to black if the `color` is `null` in the following code, which I don't like it in my case.

```
                int width = this.getSize().width;
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                if (thickness > 0)
                {
                    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));
                }
                if (color != null)
                {
                    g2.setColor(color);
                }
                g2.drawLine(startPos, 0, width - endPos, 0);
```

The **original default color** is not black. You can see this from the attached screen shot. The thinner and longer line is the original separator drawn by the call to `super.paintComponent(g)`, The thicker and shorter one is drawn by above code when `color` is `null`.

So how can I get the original default color? I tried the `color` from **getForeground()**, **getBackground()** and **getColor()** call. But none is the **original default color**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the `UIManager` to get the default color.

Check out [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for a list of default properties of Swing components